# CSS max-width has inaccurate pixel precision

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, media-queries

I have an issue with `max-width` media rule. I test to hide the elements on different `max-width` values and the behavior is inconsistent. I have tested 4 scenarios varying in the screen width.

- **Scenario 1**: Screen width is 638px: This matches my expectation.
- **Scenario 2**: Screen width is 639px: **This is wrong!** I expect `column639` still to be hidden!
- **Scenario 3**: Screen width is 640px: This matches my expectation.
- **Scenario 4**: Screen width is 641px: This matches my expectation.

**Question:**

What causes the pixels inaccuracy in the **Scenario 2** and why is `639px` value treated differently than others?

**Reproducibility:**

Strangely, it cannot be reproduced everywhere (resize the window to the width of `693px`:

- Google Chrome: I can reproduce, (`86.1.6938.200`, `64-bit`)
- Mozilla Firefox: I can reproduce, (`87.0.4280.88`, `64-bit`)
- JSFiddle: I **cannot** reproduce (all scenarios as expected):
  https://jsfiddle.net/vop23ang/
- CodePen: I can reproduce (all scenarios as expected, you need to Change View to resize horizontally): https://codepen.io/nikolas-charalambidis/pen/YzGYPGE

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>max-width issue</h1>
        <div class="column column639">
            <h2>Column 1</h2>
        </div>
          
        <div class="column column640">
            <h2>Column 2</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
.column {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: cyan;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
    .column639 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .column640 {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

**Scenarios:**

**Scenario 1:** Screen width is `638px`:
[image]

**Scenario 2:** Screen width is `639px`:
[image]

**Scenario 3:** Screen width is `640px`:
[image]

**Scenario 4:** Screen width is `641px`:
[image]

Comment: Just tried this myself on Chrome, and on my browser the column 1 does get hidden in scenario 2 as expected. Weird. I used `window.innerWidth` to get the width while resizing, if this is relevant

Comment: @AnisR.: Interestingly, JSFiddle cannot reproduce the behavior. I spent a whole evening figuring out what is going on :/

Comment: Oh wow. And indeed I was testing in JSFiddle

Comment: Could you have a look at [this Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677381&q=wrong%20incorrect%20innerWidth&can=2) and check if it is related? I came across [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453475/getting-wrong-window-height-in-chrome) where I posted the same comment. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks for the link. I really have no idea, I cannot say (my frontend proficiency is just a little above zero). However, I think of creating a bug there. It might result in more relevant information,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported and accepted as a bug reproducible on multiple versions. Currently, it's on review by the development team.

Follow the issue [#1162102](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1162102) for more details, however, I will update the answer once the issue is resolved, though.

Answer (score 1):

`max-width` is including the width limit you provide: `equal or narrower`.

> For example, this CSS will apply styles only if your browser's viewport width is equal to or narrower than 12450px:

```
@media (max-width: 12450px) { ... }
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Targeting_media_features)

---

I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oNzpgYw?editors=1111) to test that. Try it.

The result is what I would expect...

[image]

Comment: I am aware the number within `max-width` is *included*. However, it doesn't explain why `@media screen and (max-width: 639px)` does not trigger the `visibility: hidden` in the media query. Notice the **Scenario 2**  clearly shows the visible `div` although it should be still `hidden` as long as `639px` is included in the media query and satisfies the documentation.

Comment: Are you just watching the small codepen tooltip on resize in your codepen? Maybe that's the inaccurate thing...

Comment: Yes, I do. I must say this is strange: https://ibb.co/8nkvZQt

Comment: As long as I reproduce on CodePen but not on the JSFiddle, I guess the issue is related to the different implementation. The root of the problem might be that GoogleChrome handles these differently.

Comment: I tried on Chrome and FF with same result in both. I also tried with the preview frame on the left and on the right. I am mystified.

Comment: Maybe the Chrome version could be the reason for a strange behavior? Might be there anything else affecting it? Anyway, thanks for your effort.

Comment: Chrome: 87.0.4280.88 -- FF: 83.0 (but I just updated to 84.0 and no change).

Comment: Funny how your browsers version numbers are slightly different. Are you on a Mac?

Comment: I use Windows 10.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1162102